# Is there any point in using a volatile long?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

I occasionally use a `volatile` instance variable in cases where I have two threads reading from / writing to it and don't want the overhead (or potential deadlock risk) of taking out a lock; for example a timer thread periodically updating an int ID that is exposed as a getter on some class:

```
public class MyClass {
  private volatile int id;

  public MyClass() {
    ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        ++id;
      }
    }, 0L, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

My question: Given that the JLS only guarantees that 32-bit reads will be atomic is there any point in **ever** using a volatile long? (i.e. 64-bit).

**Caveat**: Please do not reply saying that using `volatile` over `synchronized` is a case of pre-optimisation; I am well aware of how / when to use `synchronized` but there are cases where `volatile` is preferable.  For example, when defining a Spring bean for use in a single-threaded application I tend to favour `volatile` instance variables, as there is no guarantee that the Spring context will initialise each bean's properties in the main thread.

Comment: Note, `++` are not atomic operations. I suggest using `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tom - It was really just a trivial example.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use `volatile` with Spring. Spring uses a lock when initializing your classes and the happens-before relations will take care of the ordering for you

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the [JLS 8.3.1.4. volatile Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) states:

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java memory model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable ([§17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)).

and, perhaps more importantly, [JLS 17.7 Non-atomic Treatment of double and long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) :

> **17.7 Non-atomic Treatment of double and long**
>   [...]
>   For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64 bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write. **Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic.** Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values.

That is, the "entire" variable is protected by the volatile modifier, not just the two parts. This tempts me to claim that it's **even more important** to use volatile for `long`s than it is for `int`s since *not even a read* is atomic for non-volatile longs/doubles.

Comment: What about `float` value , it's also 16 bytes?

Comment: I am not able to imagine what can lead to the situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64 bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write. Can you please tell?

Comment: One thread writes a 64 bit value to a variable. Since this is not an atomic operation on all hardware, this can in fact be split up into two write operations. Another thread may come along and attempt to read the value between these two write operations. It will then see a value based on 32 bits from the old value and 32 bits from the new value. See Adam's answer below.

Comment: What does this line means - "Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values."? I am confused on usage of "references"... @aioobe, if you could please clarify...

Comment: When running for example `Object o = "hello"; o = "world";` the `o` variable will always refer to either the `"hello"` object, or the `"world"` object. If the reference to `"hello"` is `0x11111111` and the reference to the  `"world"` object is `0x22222222` then `o` will never (even temporary) equal something like `0x11112222`. This is called _tearing_ and _can_ actually happen if `o` was of type `long`. (Some simplifications were made in this comment, such as `o` being a local variable and never subject o races etc)

Comment: @shaoyihe were did you get that 16 bytes from? There is no primitive type in Java with that size. `float` is a 32 bit (==4 bytes) quantity like `int`.

Answer (score 18):

This can be demonstrated by example

- constantly toggle two fields, one marked volatile and one not between all bits set and all bits clear
- read the field values on another thread
- see that the foo field (not protected with volatile) can be read in an inconsistent state, this never happens to the bar field protected with volatile

Code

```
public class VolatileTest {
    private long foo;
    private volatile long bar;
    private static final long A = 0xffffffffffffffffl;
    private static final long B = 0;
    private int clock;
    public VolatileTest() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    foo = clock % 2 == 0 ? A : B;
                    bar = clock % 2 == 0 ? A : B;
                    clock++;
                }
            }

        }).start();
        while (true) {
            long fooRead = foo;
            if (fooRead != A && fooRead != B) {
                System.err.println("foo incomplete write " + Long.toHexString(fooRead));
            }
            long barRead = bar;
            if (barRead != A && barRead != B) {
                System.err.println("bar incomplete write " + Long.toHexString(barRead));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VolatileTest();
    }
}
```

Output

```
foo incomplete write ffffffff00000000
foo incomplete write ffffffff00000000
foo incomplete write ffffffff
foo incomplete write ffffffff00000000
```

Note this only happens for me when running on a 32 bit VM, on 64 bit VM I couldn't get a single error in several minutes.

Comment: You could also add why it came to that output, it is because it writes the long in 2 steps in the first step the first 32 bit and in the second step the other 32 bit.

Answer (score 6):

"volatile" serves multiple purposes:

- guarantees atomic writes to double/long
- guarantees that when a thread A sees change in volatile variable made by thread B, thread A can also see all other changes made by thread B before the change to volatile variable (think setting the number of used cells in array after setting the cells themselves).
- prevents compiler optimization based on assumption that only one thread can change the variable (think tight loop `while (l != 0) {}`.

Is there more?