# Are 64 bit assignments in Java atomic on a 32 bit machine?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If I have code like this -

```
long x;
x  = 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

If i run this code on a 32 bit machine is it guaranteed to be atomic or is it possible that a different thread reading x, might get an incomplete/garbage value?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is the short summary:

- For references, reads/writes are *ALWAYS* atomic (even in 64 bit implementations!)
- For `int`, `char`, `byte`, `short`, `boolean`, `float`, reads/writes are *ALWAYS* atomic
- For `double` and `long`, if they're `volatile`, reads/writes are *ALWAYS* atomic

Therefore there is only exception where reads/writes may not be atomic:

- For `double` and `long`, if they're *NOT* declared `volatile`, they're *NOT GUARANTEED* to be atomic

So as far as atomicity of reading/writing shared data is concerned, you only need to make `volatile` any `double` or `long`. Everything else is already guaranteed to be atomic, regardless of how many bits are used in actual implementation.

---

#### On the specification

Here's the relevant section reproduced here for quick reference:

> #### [JLS 17.7 Non-atomic Treatment of `double` and `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)
>
> Some implementations may find it convenient to divide a single write action on a 64-bit `long` or `double` value into two write actions on adjacent 32 bit values. For efficiency's sake, this behavior is implementation specific; Java virtual machines are free to perform writes to `long` and `double` values atomically or in two parts.
>
> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-`volatile long` or `double` value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64 bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write. Writes and reads of `volatile long` and `double` values are always atomic. Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values.
>
> VM implementors are encouraged to avoid splitting their 64-bit values where possible. Programmers are encouraged to declare shared 64-bit values as `volatile` or synchronize their programs correctly to avoid possible complications.

#### See also

- [JLS 17.6 Word Tearing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6) - guarantees e.g. a `byte` can be updated without neighbor interference
- [JLS 8.3.1.4 `volatile` Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)
- [Java Tutorials/Essential Classes/Concurrency/Atomic Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

  - Note that given `int i;`, `i++` is *NOT* atomic!

#### Related questions

- [Is there any point in using a volatile long?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038203/587642)
- [How to declare array elements volatile in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236184/587642)

  - A `volatile long[]` is `volatile` *reference* to an array of `long`
  - The `long` elements themselves are not `volatile`

Comment: It seems that the javadoc assumes a 32-bit system that runs the JVM. If a 64-bit JVM runs on a 64-bit system, the read/writes of long and double, which are 64-bit, can be made atomic, at least in theory, right? I know we should still right code defensively to make it backward compatible to 32-bit systems, which implies that at long as there are 32-bit systems being used, we will have to code for the worst case scenario.

Comment: This answer seems to be implying that you'd never need e.g. a `volatile int`. This isn't the case. Volatile is also used to establish a happens-before relationship; the atomicity of a shared non-volatile `int` only guarantees that other threads will never see a garbage value. Unless you use a `volatile int`, it is legal (if unlikely) for the other threads to never see the updated value.

Comment: I quite agree with Kevin. In terms of visibility, which is defined in the memory model, a variable - all primitive type (including long and double) and reference - should be declared as volatile for other threads to see its updated value, regardless of atomicity.

Answer (score 11):

No they are not.  A  64 bit store is treated as two separate 32 bit stores.  So in a concurrent environment that variable can have the high 32 of one write and the low 32 of another write, obviously not thread safe.

Answer (score 10):

Section 8.4 of the Java Virtual Machine specification states that a double or long that is not declared volatile is treated as two 32-bit variables for load, store, read and write operations.

Furthermore, the manner of encoding and the order of the two 32-bit operations is not defined.

The spec does encourage implementations to make the operation atomic but they do not require it.

Answer (score 8):

If the variable is `volatile`, then the read/write is guaranteed atomic, but not if the variable is non-volatile.

> Some implementations may find it convenient to divide a single write
>   action on a 64-bit long or double
>   value into two write actions on
>   adjacent 32 bit values. For
>   efficiency's sake, this behavior is
>   implementation specific; Java virtual
>   machines are free to perform writes to
>   long and double values atomically or
>   in two parts.
>
> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a
>   single write to a non-volatile long or
>   double value is treated as two
>   separate writes: one to each 32-bit
>   half. This can result in a situation
>   where a thread sees the first 32 bits
>   of a 64 bit value from one write, and
>   the second 32 bits from another write.
>   Writes and reads of volatile long and
>   double values are always atomic.

[JLS 17.7 - Non-atomic Treatment of double and long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)

When multiple threads are accessing a long value without synchronization, it is necessary to use `volatile` to ensure changes made by one thread are visible to other threads, and to ensure the read/write is atomic.