# Immutable collection (an example in book of scala in depth)

Tags: scala, concurrency, atomic, immutability

In the book, it has the following example, it only sync the insert, but didn't sync lookup.I knew the currentIndex will point to a different object after insert, but is the operation of pointing to a different object atomic? example, suppose the pointer is of 8 bytes (on 64 bit machine), then at some point currentIndex will switch the pointer, but if that switch is not atomic, such as it first switch the first 4 bytes, and then switch the second 4 bytes, and if between the first and second switch, we lookup the data, then the pointer points to an object never exists and that will cause problem

```
class ImmutableService[Key, Value] extends Service[Key, Value] {
   var currentIndex = new ImmutableHashMap[Key,Value]
   def lookUp(k: Key): Option[Value] = currentIndex.get(k)
   def insert(k: Key, v: Value): Unit = synchronized {
       currentIndex = currentIndex + ((k, v))
   }
}
```

Comment: From 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756536/what-operations-in-java-are-consider-atomic
,and elsewhere, all assignments are considered atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, currentIndex is a reference - so changes to it will be done atomically.

Check:

[Are 64 bit assignments in Java atomic on a 32 bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463658/are-64-bit-assignments-in-java-atomic-on-a-32-bit-machine)